# How to make my user input as a variable to make a folder

Tags: batch-file

(c)ToTheMaker

I found this code here and I'm going to use it but the only problems is I want it to have a user input that will create the folders

For example: "Enter number of folders:"

The value which the user will input will be used as a variable that will create the folders. How am I going to do that?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

SET groupsize=10
SET n=1
SET nf=0

FOR %%f IN (*.txt) DO (
    IF !n!==1 (
        SET /A nf+=1
        MD Cake_!nf!
    )

    MOVE /Y "%%f" Cake_!nf!

    IF !n!==!groupsize! (
        SET n=1
    ) ELSE (
        SET /A n+=1
    )
)
ENDLOCAL
PAUSE
```

Comment: `help set`, specifically look at the the `set /p` option

Comment: I've already do that, but the thing is I dont understand it. Newbie in batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Executing in a command prompt window either `help set` or `set /?` results in printing several help pages into the console window for command **SET** which should be read carefully. The help explains also `set /P` for prompting user for a value or string.

```
@echo off
set "FolderCount=1"
set /P "FolderCount=Enter number of folders (default: %FolderCount%): "
for /L %%N in (1,1,%FolderCount%) do md "Folder%%N"
set "FolderCount="
```

This little batch code defines the environment variable `FolderCount` with value 1 as default value which is used when the user hits just key <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd> on prompt.

The user is asked next for the number of folders to create. The string entered by the user is assigned to environment variable `FolderCount`. The user hopefully enters a positive number and not something different.

The **FOR** loop creates the folders in current directory with name `Folder` and the current number appended which is automatically incremented by 1 on each loop run starting with value 1.

The last line deletes the environment variable `FolderCount` not needed anymore.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `md /?`
- `set /?`

**Edit:** The final batch code for the entire task with moving the text files, too.

```
@echo off
rem Delayed expansion required for variable FolderIndex in FOR loop.
rem Command setlocal additionally creates a new environment variable
rem table with copying all existing variables to the new table.
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Ask the batch user for number of subfolders to create and create them.
set "FolderCount=1"
set /P "FolderCount=Enter number of folders (default: %FolderCount%): "
for /L %%N in (1,1,%FolderCount%) do md "Folder%%N"

rem Move all *.txt files from current folder into the created subfolders.
set "FolderIndex=0"
for %%F in (*.txt) do (
    set /A FolderIndex+=1
    move /Y "%%~F" "Folder!FolderIndex!\%%~nxF"
    if !FolderIndex! == %FolderCount% set "FolderIndex=0"
)

rem Restore previous environment which results in destroying
rem current environment table with FolderIndex and FolderCount.
endlocal
```

Comment: Thank you for this bro, I'm going to comment again later if it's working!

Comment: Question for this, after creating the folders how am I able to move the files with out using the groupsize?