# How to make move files on a variable folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Someone from here give me this code to have a create number of folders depending on how many user wants

and I was thinking if I'm still able to add an algoritm that will move files equally to the folders created how am I going to do it?

```
@echo off
set "FolderCount=1"

set /P "FolderCount=Enter number of folders (default: %FolderCount%): "

for /L %%N in (1,1,%FolderCount%) do md "Folder%%N"
```

I need it badly. Any advice,suggestions,comments will be appreciated.

This is what I did

```
@echo off
set "FolderCount=1"
set /P "FolderCount=Enter number of folders (default: %FolderCount%): "
for /L %%N in (1,1,%FolderCount%)  
do md "Folder%%N"
for %%f (*.txt)

move /y "%%f" "Folder%%N"

set "FolderCount="
```

Comment: Please share your attempts by editing your post...

Comment: And what exactly is the problem that you are having? What is not happening that you expected to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make my user input as a variable to make a folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33340248/how-to-make-my-user-input-as-a-variable-to-make-a-folder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Copying* files equally to the folders created:

```
@echo off
set "FolderCount=1"
set /P "FolderCount=Enter number of folders (default: %FolderCount%): "
rem next command to treat possible answer `two` etc.
set /A "FolderCount=FolderCount"
for /L %%N in (1,1,%FolderCount%) do (
  md "Folder%%N" 2>NUL
  copy /y *.txt "Folder%%N\"
)
```

*Moving* files equally to *all* folders created:

```
@echo off
set "FolderCount=1"
set /P "FolderCount=Enter number of folders (default: %FolderCount%): "
set /A "FolderCount=FolderCount"
for /L %%N in (1,1,%FolderCount%) do (
  md "Folder%%N" 2>NUL
  if %%N EQU 1 (
     move /y "*.txt" "Folder%%N\"
  ) else (
     copy /y "Folder1\*.txt" "Folder%%N\"
  )
)
```

To `copy`/`move`  files silently, use `copy /y *.txt "Folder%%N\" >NUL 2>&1`

**Resources** (required reading):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%N` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`2>NUL`, `2>&1` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)